# Typescript: Function Overloading in Imediated Invoked Function Expression(iife)?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

So here is some code of what i am trying to achieve.

```
const someIffe = (() => {

    return function someFunction(a: number): number                 // Error '{' expected.
            function someFunction(a: string): string
            function someFunction(a: string | number) {
                return a;
    };;
})();

// This works;
function someFunction(a: number): number
function someFunction(a: string): string
function someFunction(a: string | number) {
    return a;
};
```

Any help on the same would be highly appreciated.
Thanks Regards.

Comment: There is no function overloading in JavaScript (or TypeScript). You are looking for a function interface that matches the function you have here.

Comment: Hmmmm im not sure how do we implement that. Could you please provide an example.